# Add-AzureAccount authentication without ADFS

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We're not currently federated with Azure, and Add-AzureAccount will not give me the option of using my MS Live ID for authentication. Is there a way to authenticate to Azure via PowerShell WITHOUT THE PUBLISH SETTINGS FILE? We need to use Live IDs like we do when we sign in to the portal. Error below:

Add-AzureAccount : Federated serviced at /adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed returned error: ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized.: The remote server returned an error: 
(500) Internal Server Error.

Comment: Add-AzureAccount does not rely on ADFS or any federated user info. I use Add-AzureAccount with my live.com address all the time - no problem.  Are you getting a browser dialog prompt/window when using Add-AzureAccount?  If so, are you using a Microsoft Account (e.g. Hotmail.com, live.com, etc) or is it a email account like joe at contoso.com?  And if an contoso.com account, is that an aliased Microsoft Account or an organization account?

Comment: It absolutely is trying to federate. When I enter my user creds, and I assume this because we'r federated with ACS, it redirects to my federation server. This may be because my LiveID has the same email address as the federated user account I'm authenticating to ACS with.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. When I enter my user name and then press tab, it does not allow me to enter a password and it simply redirects to my federation server.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I don't know of a way to tell the prompt that  email address is a MSFT Account vs. an organizational account. Normally that is determined by the email address. But since it seems like your email address is both a MSFT Account and an organizational account, it apparently defaults to the organizational account behavior.  The "problem" is that your account is federated, but you want MSFT Account behavior instead.  Correct?  Are you able to use another MSFT Account?